# Not able to overload output stream in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, outputstream

I am trying to overload the << operator in my class `STEntry` but keep running into this error. My class is pasted bellow the error.

```
stentry.h: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const STEntry&)’:
stentry.h:48: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)out)), ((const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)(& temp->STEntry::lexeme))) << ','’
stentry.h:46: note: candidates are: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const STEntry&)
```

My class in STEntry.h. It is pretty simple. Im trying to display some variable values.

```
#ifndef __STENTRY__
#define __STENTRY__
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class STEntry {
  public:
     string lexeme; // addr. of lexema associated with this entry
     int  tokenval; // token value for this entry
     int  offset;   // location of variable in block

     STEntry(string name = "", int newval = 0, int newoffset = 0);
     // function:  constructor ... initializes major fields

     // Relational operators:
    bool operator == (const STEntry &) const;
    bool operator != (const STEntry &) const;
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const STEntry &);
};

//--- BEGIN IMPLEMENTATION

//constructor
STEntry::STEntry(string name, int newval, int newoffset)
{
    lexeme = name;
    tokenval = newval;
    offset = newoffset;
}

// ....

//Output a single STEntry to standard output
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const STEntry & temp)
{
    out << temp.lexeme << ',' << temp.tokenval << ',' << temp.offset;
    return out;
}

//--- END OF IMPLEMENTATION
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overloaded `operator<<` just fine.  It's the line inside that function that's causing problems.

```
out << temp.lexeme << ',' << temp.tokenval << ',' << temp.offset;
```

From the error message, it doesn't know how to write `lexeme` (a `string`) into the stream.

Did you include both `<iostream>` and `<string>`?  I only see one of them in your posted code.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
#include <iostream>
```

to your file.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need include iostream before your header

Comment: Did you mean, use the includes before the ifndefs ?

Comment: @sri as Ben said you need include both iostream and string

Answer (score 1):

You may have not included any stream library into your project. Try `#include <iostream>` or `<ostream>`

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to implement the operator<< In other words you have to write it.

Also please note that __ on the macro names is reserved for use by compiler implementors and should not be used.

Comment: Yuo mean the `#ifndef __STENTRY__` ?. OK, thanks for the advice.

Comment: If you are interested: 17.6.4.3.2 Global names [global.names]
1 Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
— Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
— Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace.